# My PC doesn't detect the 6th graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

My PC is not detecting the 6th graphic card. I am using Aorus - Gigabyte -
 Z270X-Gaming - K5 - motherboard with Sapphire RX570 graphic cards and with Intel® Pentium® Processor G4560 CPU. Computer knows only 5 of the graphic cards but not the 6th. How to resolve that ?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that, your motherboard isn't actually an [Aorus motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-Z270X-Gaming-5-rev-10#sp), it appears only the LGA2066 Gaming motherboards carry that branding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by a restart.

Answer (score 2):

> How to resolve that?

You should simply restart your system.  Based on the [motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-Z270X-Gaming-5-rev-10#sp) and [CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/97143/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G4560-3M-Cache-3_50-GHz) you purchased, you should be to run more than 5 GPUs, since you have enough PCI-E lanes.

Your CPU provides at its maximum 16 PCI-E lanes itself, your motherboard's chipset at it's maximum provides 24 PCI-E lanes, due to the Z270 chipset.

It is worth pointing out that 44 lanes are the maximum number of PCI-E lanes at this time.  Additionally, based on the [hardware](https://ark.intel.com/products/98089/Intel-Z270-Chipset) you have chosen, you don't actually have 44 lanes.  This means you are already running some of those GPUs on less bandwidth than they actually require.

Even if you had 44 PCI-E lanes, you still would be short on resources, due to the requirements of each card you have.

This is all based on the fact:

> I have put the cards one by one and restarting OS after adding each new card the windows recognizes the 6 cards.